# Object with driver issue when rotating around Z- and X-axis

Tags: objects, drivers

My object (a mechanical arm) is Clamped To a curve.
I am using a driver to move this mechanical arm around the curve.

When rotating this curve around the z-axis or x-axis, the entire arm starts acting weird and changes postion.
[Click here for a more clear Video](https://youtu.be/lWrm7UdHoB0)

-32.4° Around Z-axis:
[image: Normal]
-33.6° Around Z-axis:
[image: Glitchy]
[Edit] I'm using the 'Follow Path' constraint now, which didn't work at first. I figured out that I had a problem with some of my rotations and axis. Fixing this fixed all of it.

Comment: What about the Follow Path Constraint? Drive the Offset value with a driver, that might work.